# Not able to connect to wifi with my usb wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, server, wireless, realtek-wireless, wpa-supplicant

I am using ubuntu server 20.04 and I don't have a lan connection as I am using my old pc as a server. I have a usb wifi adapter but am unable to connect to my wifi with it. when I type `iwconfig` I see that my wlan interface's i.e. usb adapter's access point : Not-Associated. So I tried wpa_supplicant to solve that but I got the error when I typed `sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlx-------` where "wlx-------" is my adapters logical name
`n180211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
n180211: deinit ifname=wlx------- disables_11b_rates=0
wlx------- : Failed to initialize driver interface`
please help how do I fix this and get my server to connect to internet through my wifi
my wireless card is `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter`

Comment: Is the wpasupplicant package installed? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I got this `Status: install ok installed` for command `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Status`

Answer (score 0):

Networking in recent Ubuntu server versions is managed by netplan. Check to see the name of your netplan file:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

I will assume that the name of the file you found is 01-netcfg.yaml. Substitute your details here if not 01-netcfg.yaml.

We will amend the file to specify your details:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Change the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx-----:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Please substitute your wireless interface name here instead of wlx----. Please note that the access point name and password are enclosed in quotation marks ". Spacing, indentation, etc. are crucial, please proofread carefully twice.

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor nano. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

If you instead prefer a static IP address for the server, you can find the template here:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml
```

Comment: I believe that indicates an error in indentation. Please use spaces, not tabs.

Comment: I am sorry it was a previous error I had copied. This is the main error`00-installer-config.yaml:20:1: Invalid yaml: aliases are not supported:` sorry

Comment: It is impossible to proofread the indentation and spacing from that. Please paste the file here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Sorry for that here I have pasted it [my yaml file](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QcqH2hd4mp/)

Comment: The password line is indented too far left. Please amend the file and try again. Reference: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml`

Comment: I checked the indentation and it worked but still `iwconfig` shows that my adapter is not associated

Comment: Ant clues in the log? `dmesg | grep wlx` It might help to reboot.

Comment: I got the following [output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xrfdnZttmn/)

Comment: There is nothing remarkable and therefore fixable there. Please confirm that wlx------ is a redaction of your actual interface name and that you used the actual name in netplan's yaml file. Also, what does this report? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep netplan`

Comment: yes wlx -- is name of my interface. And I got this  [output for cat /var/log/syslog | grep netplan](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XNBxnFMCVh/)

Comment: "So I tried wpa_supplicant to solve that" Did you write a file /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf to do that? Also, typically, in a USB wireless device, the interface name is wlx followed by the MAC address of the device. Please see  wlxd8eb9728e940 here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/715646/ubuntu-15-10-trendnet-tew-648ubm-internet-drops If your device actually shows wlx--------,then I suspect that you either have a faulty device or a counterfeit device. I am not at all sure that any networking will work properly without any MAC address.

Comment: Yes I created `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` & the interface name is wlx followed by mac address of the device

Comment: So, contrary to your comment above, wlx-------- is *not* the logical name of your device. I'm very confused now.

Comment: Yes it's wlx0089... Something

Comment: Adapter is realtek rtl8188su